# Esconder os últimos 4 números de uma string

Tags: php

Tenho uma *string* do valor `187.10.61.291`, quero uma função que pegue os últimos 4 números e transforme em `*`.

Exemplo de resultado esperado:

> `192.1**.*.*` ou `192.16*.**.*` ou `192.168.***.*` ou `192.168.**.**`

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: como ficaria esses ips da forma q vc quer? 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.10.1 - 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.10.10

Comment: 192.1**.*.* - 192.16*.**.* - 192.168.***.* - 192.168.**.**

Comment: Está um pouco confusa a pergunta: "quatro últimos números", mas não são só 3 últimos? ou você quis dizer "4 últimos caracteres"?

Comment: 4 últimos números, por exemplo: 187.10.6*.***

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Outra opção é usar `strrev()` para inverter a string ou seja `192.168.39.134` vira `431.93.861.291` e aplicar uma expressão regular para substituir os 4 primeiros números esse limite é definido no quarto argumento de `preg_replace()` e por último mais uma chamada de `strrev()` para voltar a string ao 'estado original'.

```
$str = strrev(preg_replace('/\d/', '*',  strrev('192.168.39.134'), 4));
```

Exemplos

```
192.168.0.1
192.1**.*.*

192.168.254.1
192.168.***.*

192.168.25.12
192.168.**.**

192.168.25.123
192.168.2*.***
```

Comment: Também não entendi o porquê do -1. A resposta está correta, vou repor o +1.

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu o negativo, nem acho que isso justifique, mas acho que usar 2 strrev é matar a formiga na basuka.

Comment: @rray entendi a ideia do Strrev. É por conta da limitação de substituição de caracteres, não é? Parece que o PHP tem uma limitação quanto a isso.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu não conheço um jeito simples de substituir apenas os 4 últimos números do IP então o `strrev()` 'joga' eles no começo, ai consigo forçar o número de substituições com `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Acho que esta solução é a que chega perfeitamente ao resultado desejado pelo AP :)

Answer (score 6):

Segue solução com operações básicas de *string*:

```
substr( $ip, 0, strrpos( $ip, '.' ) ).'.***';
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lCphRO)**

Caso queira realmente trocar 4 dígitos:

```
substr( $ip, 0, strrpos( $ip, '.' ) - 1 ).'*.***';
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/co81tc)**

Se precisar que a função ignore IPs mal formados, pode usar um `if`:

```
function masked_ip( $ip ) {
    if( substr_count( $ip, '.' ) < 3 ) return $ip; // ou return '***.***.***.***';
    return substr( $ip, 0, strrpos( $ip, '.' ) - 1 ).'*.***';
}
```

### Alternativas com `explode`:

Baseado num comentário do @rray no chat, segue uma versão com `explode`:

Para 4 dígitos:

```
function masked_ip( $ip ) {
    $ocs = explode( '.', $ip );
    $ocs[2]{strlen($ocs[2])-1} = '*';
    $ocs[3]='***';
    return implode( '.', $ocs );
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nnLkJ5)**

Para 3 dígitos:

```
function masked_ip( $ip ) {
    $ocs = explode( '.', $ip );
    $ocs[3]='***';
    return implode( '.', $ocs );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Se quiser que ele considere qualquer numero, antes e depois de um ponto pode usar um for com trabalhando a string de maneira semelhante a um vetor:

```
<?php

function maskIp($value) {
    $len = strlen($value);
    $j = 0;

    for ($i = $len - 1; $j < 4 && $i > -1; --$i) {
        if (ctype_digit($value{$i})) {
            ++$j;
            $value{$i} = '*';
        }
    }

    return $value;
}

echo maskIp('127.0.0.100'), '<br>';
echo maskIp('127.0.0.10'), '<br>';
echo maskIp('127.0.0.1'), '<br>';
echo maskIp('127.0.255.100'), '<br>';
echo maskIp('127.0.25.100'), '<br>';
```

Exemplo http://ideone.com/EyyOxD

Outra sugestão (antes da edição da pergunta), com regex seria algo como (esse é um exemplo para entender a regex):

```
function maskIp($value) {
    $re  = '\d\.\d{3}|';    //Checa terminado com 5.255 por exemplo
    $re .= '\d{2}\.\d{2}|'; //Checa terminado com 55.125 por exemplo
    $re .= '\d{3}\.\d{1}';  //Checa terminado com 255.1 por exemplo

    return preg_replace('/(' . $re . ')$/', '*.***', $value);
}

echo maskIp('192.168.100.100'), PHP_EOL;
echo maskIp('192.168.100.10'), PHP_EOL;
echo maskIp('192.168.100.1'), PHP_EOL;
```

Seguindo um pouco a ideia do @rray com a ideia do @Bacco de interpretar números 1 ou 2 números após o ponto como sendo 3 asteriscos também.

Simplificando o exemplo:

```
function maskIp($value) {
    return preg_replace('/('\d\.\d{3}|d{2}\.\d{2}|\d{3}\.\d{1})$/', '*.***', $value);
}

echo maskIp('192.168.100.100'), PHP_EOL;
echo maskIp('192.168.100.10'), PHP_EOL;
echo maskIp('192.168.100.1'), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: +1 custei a entender, mas agora vi porque você fez um "três pra lá, um pra cá".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu ia fazer tudo junto, mas dividi pro AP entender a Regex :)

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente este é o código para o que vc quer

```
$new = substr("187.10.61.291", 0, -4) . 'xxxx';
```

o retorno disso é

```
187.10.61xxxx
```

Comment: Tem como o ``substr`` colocar o ponto tambem? Ou alguma função que faça isso?

Comment: @STRILEXLIVE... basta adicionar um ponto ali antes do primeiro "x".

Comment: Apesar da resposta ter sido benquista, parece-me que a intenção do AP era outra. Usando `substr` ele "cortará" qualquer valor, independente de ser número ou ponto e colocará `x` no final. O AP deixou isso nos comentários: `192.1**.*.* - 192.16*.**.* - 192.168.***.* - 192.168.**.**`. Seria interessante a edição da resposta

Comment: Deixei o meu -1 também, pois ainda não houve uma posição sobre a edição da resposta.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta dá a entender que você precisa eliminar os 3 últimos números depois do último ponto. Ou seja, os 4 últimos caracteres do `IP` precisam ficar como `.***`.

Sendo assim, eu faria dessa forma:

```
preg_replace('/\d+$/', '***', '192.168.1.122')
```

A expressão `\d+` capturará apenas valores numéricos. O caractere `$` está informando que somente expressões que terminem com `\d` (dígitos).

## Atualização

Se você quer capturar os últimos 4 números e transformá-lo em `*`, ignorando ao `.`, sugiro a utilização do seguinte código:

```
preg_replace('/\d{1}\.\d+$/D', '*.***', '192.168.100.122')
preg_replace('/\d{1}\.\d+$/D', '*.***', '192.168.1.100')
```

Resultado:

```
192.168.10*.***
192.168.*.***
```

## Usando `preg_replace_callback`.

Também consegui elaborar uma maneira de capturar os 4 últimos dígitos, considerando que o caractere `.` deve permanecer.

Veja:

```
$replacer = function ($m) {
    return str_repeat('*', strlen($m[1])) . '.' . str_repeat('*', strlen($m[2]));
};

$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d{1})\.(\d{1,3})$/', $replacer, '192.468.1.114');
```

Veja o exemplo do `preg_replace_callback` no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/PaqyhS)